# How to debug the consoleapplication in vscode for windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know how to debug console application in visual studio code for windows.
Can anybody guide me? I tried to google the tutorial, but still not solve my problem.

Sorry my 50 cent question.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode only supports node and mono debugging at the moment.
You can find a guide for node debugging here https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/nodejs